# Get df.loc['column_name'] when column_name is a variable in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a variable that I call `response` where the user manually inputs the words "Apple" or "Tree".

Then I want to select the column whose name = "Apple" or "Tree" based on user answer.

How can I do this?
Something like `df.loc[response]` ?

Comment: The answer is simply `df[response]` as you have already guessed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access column with `response` variable like

```
df[response]
```

`df[response]` will evaluate to `df['Apple']` or `df['tree']` depending on what you have in response variable

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is :

```
df[response]
```

where response is the variable which can either be "Apple or "Tree".